# Passing data from the module controller to a widget in PyroCMS

Tags: pyrocms

Can I pass custom data from the module's controller to widgets(when it is being used as a tag in the module view) programatically? Or does this violate the concept of widgets being self contained?

Answer (score 1):

Wow, 4 months passed but hope this helps:

Let's say that you have a module named "example" in:

```
/addons/modules/example/
```

Create a "widgets" folder under "example" module directory and create your widget there:

In this case widget controller filename will be:

```
/addons/modules/example/widgets/something/something.php
```

Its content:

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Widget_Something extends Widgets
{
    public $author         = 'Author';
    public $website     = 'site';
    public $version     = '1.0';

    public function run($options)
    {
       // Load your modules model
       $this->load->model("example/example_m");

       // And/Or load your modules library
       $this->load->library("example/some_library");

       // Return values to use in view
       return array(
           'variable_name'   => $this->example_m->get_some_data(),
           'variable_name_2' => $this->example_m->get_some_other_data()
       ); 
    }
}
```

And its view will be in:

```
/addons/modules/example/widgets/something/views/display.php
```

View content:

```
<h2>Some html</h2>
<p>And the variable from controller:</p>
<p><?php echo $variable_name;?></p>
```

For more info you can look under blog module directory. There you will see widgets.

Otherwise there is always pyrocms.com:

http://www.pyrocms.com/docs/manuals/developers/creating-custom-widgets